# HTTPS通信でcertificate verify failedエラー

Tags: ruby, https

Rubyでサーバー間通信を行うために以下のコードを実装したのですが、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。足りない点などありましたらアドバイスいただけないでしょうか。

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

実装

```
  require 'net/https'
  ～～
  https = Net::HTTP.new('ホスト', 443)
  https.open_timeout = SYSTEM_TIMEOUT_SEC
  https.read_timeout = SYSTEM_TIMEOUT_SEC
  https.use_ssl = true
  https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  https.verify_depth = 5
  https.ca_file = "./cacert.pem"
```

cacert.pemは以下で取得し、上記の実装ファイルと同じ階層に置いています。
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

以下を指定して証明書を無視した場合は通信できており、

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

cert.pemが本当に存在しているのか以下のコマンドを実行すると、
証明書情報が出力されていたので保存されているのだと思います。
$  cat （ファイルパス）/cacert.pem

ちなみに、以下は接続したと出力されたのですが、HTTPSを指定すると
接続を拒否されています。なにかサーバへの設定が必要なのでしょうか？

```
$ wget -S --spider http://xx.xx.xx.xx
スパイダーモードが有効です。リモートファイルが存在してるか確認します。
--2018-05-10 09:27:27--  http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
xx.xx.xx.xx:80 に接続しています... 接続しました。
HTTP による接続要求を送信しました、応答を待っています...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
　～～

$  wget -S --spider https://xx.xx.xx.xx
スパイダーモードが有効です。リモートファイルが存在してるか確認します。
--2018-05-10 09:28:06--  https://xx.xx.xx.xx/
xx.xx.xx.xx:443 に接続しています... 失敗しました: 接続を拒否されました.
```

Comment: wget でのテストで、`https://xx.xx.xx.xx` はもしかして IP アドレスで指定しているのでしょうか?

Comment: wget さま　IPアドレスになります

Comment: [OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket#verify_result](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/OpenSSL=3a=3aSSL=3a=3aSSLSocket/i/verify_result.html) で SSLの検証結果を参照できるみたいです。エラーコードを確認スレばなにかわかるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

原因が解るわけではないのですが、気になる点もありますので、回答としてまとめておきます。

- `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

  CA 証明書(つまり `cacert.pem`)が見つからない場合に発生することが多いようです。
  以下の `https.ca_file = "./cacert.pem"` の項目を確認してください。
- `https = Net::HTTP.new('ホスト', 443)`

  `'ホスト'` と書かれているので判りにくいのですが、ここに IP アドレスは指定できません。必ずホスト名を指定してください。そしてそのホスト名はサーバ証明書に記載されている必要があります。
- `https.ca_file = "./cacert.pem"`

  `./` の部分は、実装ファイルと同じ階層という意味でなく、実行時のカレントディレクトリを意味します。階層は合っていますか?
- 「cert.pemが本当に存在しているのか」

  `cert.pem` ではなく `cacert.pem` のはずです。
- `wget -S --spider https://xx.xx.xx.xx`

  `https = Net::HTTP.new('ホスト', 443)` の場合と同様、https では IP アドレスの指定はできません。ホスト名を指定してください。

  ただし、IP アドレスで指定したからといって「接続を拒否されました」にはならないはずで、
  nginx (または apache 等) やファイアウォールの設定を確認する必要があるのかもしれません。

以上です。解決につながることを祈ります。

---

HTTPS (というか SSL/TLS) では、証明書の検証をします。

例えば `https://example.com` にアクセスすると、example.com がサーバ証明書を送ってくるので、その証明書が偽造されたものでないことと、その証明書の中の Common Name (CN) または Subject Alt Name に `example.com` と記載されていることを確認します。

これが証明書の検証です。

`Net::HTTP.new('ホスト名', 443)` の場合、指定した`ホスト名`が証明書の中に記載されていることを確認します。

同様に、`Net::HTTP.new('IPアドレス', 443)` の場合、指定した`IPアドレス`が証明書の中に記載されていることを確認します。しかし、証明書の中に IP アドレスは記載されていないため、検証は失敗し、そこでエラーとなります。

この検証は、verify_mode を VERIFY_PEER にすると行われますが、VERIFY_NONE の時は行われません。VERIFY_NONE にすると実行できるのは証明書を検証していないためです。

Comment: masmさま　コメントありがとうございます。cacert.pemについて、ファイル名を再度確認し、対応しましたが、やはり同じエラーとなってしまいました。https = Net::HTTP.new(IPアドレス, 443)　このようにしていますが、Net::HTTPはIPアドレスを指定して実行はできないのでしょうか？（ちなみに、https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONEを指定した場合、HTTPSで実行できているのが、なぜなのかわかりませんでした…）

Comment: @kanko 回答に追記しました。